# Rails use engine to mock up an REST api backend services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

So I am trying to use engine in rails to mock up an Rest api backend for development and testing purposes such that I don't have to rely on the REST api. As I come across with this I have a couple questions that I am trying to understands.

I am guessing the idea is that. First have my engine and my rails app running con-currently and in my engine, have a controller handle when my rails app calls a url rest call it will render the json object(mock data) that I have it in my engine.

1. Does the engine and the rails app have to run with unicorn gem concurrently? or if the engine can just live inside of the rails app
2. how do I redirect the url rest call from my rails app such that it goes to my mock engine ? I am guessing something has to do with addressable or routing ?

I have followed [2] to create a mountable engine and I was hoping if i can get some direction about this topic and where everything should go

[1] http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

[2] http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines?view=comments

In my engine

```
|controller 
|-data
|--apple.json     
|-fruits_client
|--apple_controller.rb
|lib
|-fruist_client
|--apple.rb
|--engine.rb
```

Comment: Did you mount the engine inside the routes file?

Answer (score 1):

You should mount your Engine.

In the routes of your main application add the following:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :as => 'my_engine'
```

Then you can use: `my_engine.something_url`

You can set the mounting point at any place. If you want to use the same root as your main application you can use:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/', :as => 'my_engine'
```

If you want to call your engine using a namespace, for example "fruits":

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/fruits', :as => 'my_engine'
```

To use your engine you should have it's path in your Gemfile. It should look something like

```
gem 'my_engine', :path => '/path/to/my_engine'
```

Comment: for example. if i have this rest call get(http://localhost:8080/fruits/apple). Ideally, after I mounted the engine. do i just set my engine as the base URL (http://localhost:8080) and call http://localhost:8080.fruits/apple and instead of the . can i just call /fruits/apple and get the data back ? so I don't have to change anything in the rest call

Comment: another question. where do i put my engine inside of my rails app ?

Comment: You can use mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/', :as => 'my_engine'

Comment: I would place the engine anywhere in my machine as far as I know the path to get it. After that I would add the path to it in my Gemfile. Something like gem 'my_engine', :path => '/luis/my_engine'

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that out and give you some updates.